# Prove (or give a counterexample) Decreasing nest of finite open intervals is {L}

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Prove or give a counterexample: if $a_{n} \uparrow$ and $b_n \downarrow$, and $(a_n , b_n)$ is a decreasing nest of finite open intervals, then $\exists L \in \mathbb{R} $, such that

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n, b_n) = \{L\}$$

I start as follows:
$b_n$ is bounded below by $a_n$, as well as $b_n \downarrow$ so it has a limit, called $L_1$, likewise for $a_n$ having limit $L_2$

Now I'm stuck because I'm pretty sure I have to prove $L_1 = L_2 =L $, but I don't know how to get there. I know $a_n < b_n$ and therefore $ L_2 \leq L_1$, but I don't know how to prove that they're equivalent. $L_1$ should be the greatest lower bound of $b_n$ and $L_2$ the least upper bound of $a_n$, but that doesn't get me anywhere either.

Comment: What do you mean by a "finite open interval"? Having finitely many points? There is no such thing, at least if you work with the real line. Do you mean bounded open intervals?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have a hard time proving this, because it's not true.  Consider
$a_n=-1/n$ and $b_n=1+1/n$. Here,
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (a_n,b_n)=[0,1].$$

Comment: Huh, I'm really bad at finding counterexamples.

Comment: Sometimes it hard to find a counter example if you're looking for a proof. :)

Answer (score 0):

consider $a_n=0$ and $b_n = 1/n$, then $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n, b_n) = \emptyset$$

for the strictly increasing case, consider $a_n= -1-1/n , b_n=1/n$ , then $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n, b_n) = [-1,0]$, which is not singleton.

Comment: The problem is to prove or provide a counter example.  This does neither.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski this is a counter example... why dont you think so?

Comment: This would be a counterexample, but the OP asks for $a_n$ to be *increasing* (at least, that's how I interpret "$a_n\uparrow$") - that said, "$\{\emptyset\}$" is not the same as "$\emptyset$"!

Comment: @NoahSchweber  I am not an expert in set theory, so I dont bother about those notations, and I generally think "increasing" as a non decreasing function unless untill it is not mentioned to be "strict"

Comment: It was my mistake not including the precise definition, $a_n \uparrow$ is strictly increasing. I am still learning this, so I'm not sure which notations are standardized.

Comment: "$a_n\uparrow$" is (as far as I know) not standard notation; I just assumed that was how you meant it (partly because if we assume strictness, then we **do** get that the intersection is nonempty, which makes the problem more interesting).